# send sms with a preset phone number

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I want to send an sms message and this code snippet works:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Check out this Punchit app!
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.punchit");  
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Now I want to preset the phone number and tried both of the following:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9999999999" ));
```

and

```
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, "9999999999");
```

Neither of these two statements work, so what is the correct syntax for presetting a phone number?

Answer (score 0):

test as follows:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello1");
sendIntent.putExtra("address", "12345");
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms")
```

Comment: and how to send out the sms without having to click on send ??